# Set Cookie in XHR response : How different browsers handle this?

Tags: appsec, javascript, ajax

If I send a XHR request to `example.com` and response has `Set-Cookie: dummyCookie=dummy`  in response. 
How different browsers handle this?

- Does any version of any browser set the cookie for example.com, so that it will travel in subsequent requests(requests in compliance to SOP) to example.com

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if browsershots will handle this - since it seems to be mainly focused on *looks*, rather than behaviour.

An XHR response, if it issues a "Set-Cookie" header, it will be included in further requests.  From http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest:

```
 If the user agent supports HTTP State Management it should persist, discard
 and send cookies (as received in the Set-Cookie response header, and sent in
 the Cookie header) as applicable.
```

I just tested in FF13, and XHR requests set cookie values.

Comment: Having said that, ensure that you have the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property enabled to include credentials (and thus also cookie values) in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of XHR request depends on browsers' implementation. 
The answer for your question (about `Set-Cookie` and all stuff related to XHR SOP) are here:
http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe the browser will accept the cookie from the server, if you're allowed to send the request.  I believe this should be true on all modern browsers.

But you can always test it yourself, if in doubt.  [Browsershots](https://browsershots.org/) is a great tool for this sort of thing, and it is free.